# Instagram : Implementing related tag search

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

For my website I need to implement a tag search functionality from Instagram which functions like, if user submits a tag name then show response for all tags with word match and also related tags too. As per the docs,

```
https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_search
```

I am now able to fetch results for word match search only, is it possible to get related tags also via api ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the endpoint that you referenced, `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search`, your results will contain a tag that matches your search if available and also other tags that are similar.

So if you searched for the tag "dogfood", you might also get other suggested tags such as:

- dogfoods
- dogfoodfordays
- dogfoodlover
- dogfoodcoupons

and so on.

Comment: But that's just word matches, the OP already new that. He's looking for related tags like 'pet', 'dog', 'yummy' etc.